# SQL Server Extended Stored Procedures

Tags: sql-server, windows, stored-procedures

I know Extended Stored Procedures are yesterday's news, but they still have their place.

Does anyone know how to get the current Connection ID from inside an Extended Stored Procedure?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Using extended stored procedures from .NET your code is executed from CLR hosted into SQLServer. For this reason you don't need to "relogin", you can connect to the existing context using [context connection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131053.aspx) string "Context Connection=true". Then you can get the session ID of the current user process using `@@SPID` t-sql command.

Try this snippet of code:

```
using (var cnn = new SqlConnection("context connection=true"))
{
    cnn.Open();     
    using(var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT @@SPID", cnn))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar()));
    }
}
```